# ASP.NET get username and password from NTLM authenticatiuon form

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication, ntlm

I've ASP.NET application with Windows Authentication.

How to get the username and password in ASP.NET from the form provided by Windows authentication method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the currently logged on user's username with:

```
string username = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

But you can't capture the password. Why would you need to anyways? Authentication occurs before your page is executed, and the password is never sent down the wire;

In your IIS application for Dynamics, you need to enable Windows Authentication, you do this through IIS manager. Click the Dynamics IIS website, then select Authentication, make sure you disable Anonymous Authentication, and enable Windows Authentication.

Comment: I want to authenticate the user asp.net and in the CRM using the same credentials

Comment: @sultan - You need to explain more... is the CRM running on ASP.NET? What authentication mechanisms does it support?

Comment: I use `Dynamics CRM 2011` it supports `Windows` authentication and asp application too

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing the existing answer, note that in newer incarnations of ASP.NET, such as ASP.NET Core but also OWIN .NET Framework apps, `LoginUserIdentity` no longer exists on `Request`, and instead, one would use

```
User.Identity.Name
```

cf. e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475929/5085211).